# Filtering by custom UUIDField got broken with Django 3.2 upgrade

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Django project that I've recently upgraded from Django 2.2 to 3.2. In this project, I use a custom `UUIDField` that saves UUIDs to MySQL as `char(36)` in the following format: `12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678`.

```py
import uuid

from django.db import models


class UUIDField(models.UUIDField):
    """
    Overrides Django UUIDField to store full UUID's including dashes.
    """
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)
        self.max_length = 36

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "CharField"

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
            try:
                value = uuid.UUID(value)
            except AttributeError:
                raise TypeError(self.error_messages['invalid'] % {'value': value})

        if connection.features.has_native_uuid_field:
            return value
        return str(value)
```

After the upgrade, I noticed that searching for full UUIDs didn't work anymore. If I only provide the first part of the UUID (up to the first character after the first hyphen) it works as expected.

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Mar 15 2022, 13:55:28)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from foobar.foo.models import Foo
>>>
>>> Foo.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Foo: Foo object (34c46fe8-caf0-11ec-bdb9-482ae362a4c0)>]>
>>>
>>> Foo.objects.filter(id__icontains='34c46fe8-caf0-11ec-bdb9-482ae362a4c0')
<QuerySet []>
>>>
>>> Foo.objects.filter(id__icontains='34c46fe8-')
<QuerySet [<Foo: Foo object (34c46fe8-caf0-11ec-bdb9-482ae362a4c0)>]>
>>>
>>> Foo.objects.filter(id__icontains='34c46fe8-c')
<QuerySet []>
>>>
```

I've played with the `UUIDField` methods, but I can't seem to figure out what went wrong. Here's a link to a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/milonoir/080ecfe1d0fa52df0a0c4a6ab265dde0) using a simplified model where I got the above shell example from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quite long `pdb` debugging session, I managed to find what the problem is. I was hoping to find raw SQL snippets along the way, but instead an object called `WhereNode` caught my attention.

```
> /home/milanb/temp/django_custom_uuid_field/django_playground/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py(1399)build_filter()
-> return clause, used_joins if not require_outer else ()
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /home/milanb/temp/django_custom_uuid_field/django_playground/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py(1399)build_filter()->(<WhereNode: (...f9c4f880be0>)>, {'foo_foo'})
-> return clause, used_joins if not require_outer else ()
(Pdb) retval
(<WhereNode: (AND: <django.db.models.lookups.UUIDIContains object at 0x7f9c4f880be0>)>, {'foo_foo'})
(Pdb) pp locals()
{'__return__': (<WhereNode: (AND: <django.db.models.lookups.UUIDIContains object at 0x7f9c4f880be0>)>,
                {'foo_foo'}),
 'alias': 'foo_foo',
 'allow_joins': True,
 'allow_many': True,
 'arg': 'id__icontains',
 'branch_negated': False,
 'can_reuse': {'foo_foo'},
 'check_filterable': True,
 'clause': <WhereNode: (AND: <django.db.models.lookups.UUIDIContains object at 0x7f9c4f880be0>)>,
 'col': Col(foo_foo, foo.Foo.id),
 'condition': <django.db.models.lookups.UUIDIContains object at 0x7f9c4f880be0>,
 'current_negated': False,
 'filter_expr': ('id__icontains', '34c46fe8-caf0-11ec-bdb9-482ae362a4c0'),
 'join_info': JoinInfo(final_field=<foobar.foo.fields.UUIDField: id>, targets=(<foobar.foo.fields.UUIDField: id>,), opts=<Options for Foo>, joins=['foo_foo'], path=[], transform_function=<function Query.setup_joins.<locals>.final_transformer at 0x7f9c4f89ca60>),
 'join_list': ['foo_foo'],
 'lookup_type': 'icontains',
 'lookups': ['icontains'],
 'opts': <Options for Foo>,
 'parts': ['id'],
 'pre_joins': {},
 'reffed_expression': False,
 'require_outer': False,
 'reuse_with_filtered_relation': False,
 'self': <django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x7f9c4f902c18>,
 'split_subq': True,
 'targets': (<foobar.foo.fields.UUIDField: id>,),
 'used_joins': {'foo_foo'},
 'value': '34c46fe8-caf0-11ec-bdb9-482ae362a4c0'}
(Pdb) pp clause
<WhereNode: (AND: <django.db.models.lookups.UUIDIContains object at 0x7f9c4f880be0>)>
```

Here I noticed this particular line:

```
 'clause': <WhereNode: (AND: <django.db.models.lookups.UUIDIContains object at 0x7f9c4f880be0>)>,
```

I didn't know what a `django.db.models.lookups.UUIDIContains` object was, so went straight to Django's source code to find out. This is en empty class made of two mixins `IContains` and [`UUIDTextMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/08e6073f878264a0c091da0d3db456820252ef6c/django/db/models/lookups.py#L608-L620). The latter was the culprit in my case as it removed all hyphens from the lookup value. This was [introduced as a fix](https://github.com/django/django/commit/d9881a025c15d87b2a7883ee50771117450ea90d) after version 2.2, which I used before the upgrade, in order to support database backends without a native UUID type (e.g. MySQL 5.7 in my case).

The fix was very easy, I just had to register a custom `UUIDIContains` class without the `UUIDTextMixin` for my custom `UUIDField`.

My new `fields.py`:

```py
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.lookups import IContains


class UUIDField(models.UUIDField):
    """
    Overrides Django UUIDField to store full UUID's including dashes.
    """
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)
        self.max_length = 36

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "CharField"

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
            try:
                value = uuid.UUID(value)
            except AttributeError:
                raise TypeError(self.error_messages['invalid'] % {'value': value})

        if connection.features.has_native_uuid_field:
            return value
        return str(value)


@UUIDField.register_lookup
class UUIDIContains(IContains):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Milo got the answer but I also had to do this for the iexact lookup in my case.  I'm using MSSQL native uuid, through a custom UUID fields as well since no backend supports the native version it seems. But MSSQL doesn't support the dash-less version of uuid.

My UUIDField is slightly different but I also had to add register the IExact lookup with out the UUIDTextMixin.

```
@UUIDField.register_lookup
class UUIDIExact(IExact):
    pass
```